# Convert ranges of rows in Excel to pdf file with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I want to convert ranges of rows in Excel to pdf file with VBA, with specific format in a different sheet.

My code is ignoring rows with similar values.

I want to add all the rows with similar values under the pdf file because other columns related to those rows contain information to be included in the pdf.

For example:
**The data set**
[image: the first image shows how the data are in the data set]

**Format of the output**
[image: second image is the format of the output]

I want EmpID as input and the related rows with that EmpID will be the output and the rows will be included sequentially in the output.

**Expected output**
[image: expected output]

The problem is it generates the output of only one row with the number for example 430 and ignores other 5 rows and goes for the next unique number.

I have tried to match from one Excel sheet to another with VLOOKUP so that with a certain Emp_ID value the the rows will get certain outputs.

```vb
Sub pdf_test_7()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To 10

    Sheets("ps").Cells(1, 2) = Sheets("WD").Cells(i, 1)
    
    Sheets("ps").Range("A1:Q25").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
      Filename:="C:\Users\Desktop\test_code_for_printing_pdf\" & Sheets("WD").Cells(i, 1) & ".pdf", _
      Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
      IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
      OpenAfterPublish:=False
    
Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try setting `IgnorePrintAreas:=False`?

Comment: Yes I did. :( but does not work.

Comment: Ok. I've used a different method. I select the top left cell and set a range variable to equal the `CurrentRegion`, then set the print area to that range. Also, `IgnorePrintAreas:=False`. I do this inside the loop. This should let your print range change with the EmpId rows.

Comment: Can you share how you did it then i could have get an idea how you processed your work?

Comment: I'm on my phone but I'll post an answer that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub pdf_test_7()
Dim i As Long
Dim ws as Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("ps")

  With ws
   .PageSetup.PrintArea = .Range("A1:Q25").Address

   For i = 2 To 10

      .Cells(1, 2) = Sheets("WD").Cells(i, 1)

      .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
      Filename:="C:\Users\Desktop\test_code_for_printing_pdf\" & Sheets("WD").Cells(i, 1) & ".pdf", _
      Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
      IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
      OpenAfterPublish:=False

   Next i 
  End With

 Set ws = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, still gives the single row output not all the rows as output. I was thinking whether excel is ignoring the rows with similar values or not. because the rows I have, they have similar values for each employee for example : one employee has EmpID '430' and he has with the same ID 4 other rows with different information. the output of the VBA code you have provided as well as mine somehow takes the first row and then it jumps for the other unique EmpID. do you have any suggestion on that?

Comment: @green_world07 I'm afraid I'm stumped. I just wonder if the procedure's changes in EmpId deliver the expected list. Are you using `FILTER()` to return the rows for EmpId?

Comment: No i am not using any filter.

Comment: All I can suggest is that you set a break point at the beginning of your for loop and step through the code. Use the watch window to see when variables change values or add debug.print statements inside your code to check values.